# Amazon S3 Data integrity MD5 vs SSL/TLS

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, md5, tls1.2

I'm currently working with the Amazon S3 API, and have a general wondering about the server-side integrity checks that can be done if you provide the MD5 hash during posting of an object.

I'm not sure I understand if the integrity check is required if you send the data (I'm assuming the object data you're posting also) via SSL/TLS, which provide their own support for data integrity in transit.

Should you send the digest regardless if you're posting over SSL/TLS? Isn't it superfluous to do so? Or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrity checking provided by TLS provides no guarantees about what happens going into the TLS wrapper at the sender side, or coming out of it and being written to disk at the receiver.

So, no, it is not entirely superfluous because TLS is not completely end-to-end -- the unencrypted data is still processed, however little, on both ends of the connection... and any hardware or software that touches the unencrypted bits can malfunction and mangle them.

S3 gives you an integrity checking mechanism -- two, if you use both `Content-MD5` and `x-amz-content-sha256` -- and it seems unthinkable to try to justify bypassing them.

Comment: I wasn't trying to justify bypassing them if it came off as that. Just trying to understand the reasoning. But I find it strange to hear that TLS is not completely end to end. I understand that before data enters the TLS channel and after it exists there is still a window where it can be mangled or corrupted. But then why is this not a concern for all the traffic being sent over TLS daily? I would imagine that banking or other secret info being sent regularly over TLS is much more important that it is sent and arrives integrally.

Comment: And if this is the reasoning isn't there still a window (true, smaller than without) for corruption after the digest integrity check is performed and data is persisted on disk? Is this effort just to minimize as much as possible the chance for corruption? But again, if I understood this correctly, I still find it strange that this sort of care isn't being done for all data being pushed around over TLS, if this is indeed such a risk

Comment: Again, not trying to justify not using it, I imagine smarter people than me designed this. Just trying to understand :)

Comment: I just realized the MD5Digest is optional when pushing object via S3, so then I guess it's just an extra measure of safety?